# URL is too long while running !!

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010, query-string, web

I am creating a website using LINQ database on Visual studio 2010 
i am getting this error when i make many queries from the database and to database

the page contains dropdown list that get something from the database and at the same time posts back to get queries from the database and bind it to Gridviews

after 3 queries from the database it shows this message

**"The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value."**

i am using Google chrome BTW!

Comment: Do you happen to use AJAX? Can you please post some relevant code and the full exact error plus the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/a33611c1-7cdf-4a40-880b-3309456406f0:

> Please check the section in your config file: 
>   `<httpRuntime maxRequestPathLength="260" maxQueryStringLength="2048" />` 
>   By default,
>   the query string lengths was constrainted to 2048 characters. To allow
>   longer or shorter query strings, modify the maxQueryStringLength
>   attribute, please.

Comment: Any time. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not seeing your code can't tell you how to reduce the length of that querystring. What information are you passing in the querystring?

Here is [an article](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/forms/what-is-the-limit-on-querystring/get/url-parameters.html) that attempts to quantify the thresholds (it varies by OS/browser combo)

Comment: The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

Comment: Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below

Comment: Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9016221
   System.Web.ValidateRequestExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +35
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `GET` method to send your data back to the server use the `POST` method.

In your html change your form tag to something like this

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="...">
```

Or if your submiting the form via javascript try something like this

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
myForm.method = "POST";
myForm.submit();
```

Comment: how could i use Post methods ??

Comment: <asp:Content ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" 
    contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1">
    <form id="form1" method="post"  runat="server">

Comment: After making it like that . it is using the URL again